# System.InvalidCastException for Frame in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Excuse my ignorance since I'm a newbie. I'm creating a page using xaml (as the project is xamarin forms). In this page, I have `<Frame>` block. In this frame block, I have `Image` and `Label` as seen below.

```
<Frame BorderColor="Black" Padding="16" Margin="5">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Label x:Name="game1Date" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" Font="{StaticResource classicFont}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="flag1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Image x:Name="flag2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
            <Label x:Name="team1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource gray}" FontSize="22"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Label TextColor="{StaticResource gray}" Text="-" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="40"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" >
            <Label x:Name="team2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource gray}" FontSize="22"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

And resource dictionary

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="orange">#ff8900</Color>
        <Color x:Key="live">#ee4142</Color>
        <Color x:Key="gray">#333000</Color>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="boldFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="ConcourseT4-Bold.tff#Concourse T4-Bold" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="ConcourseT4-Bold" />
        </OnPlatform>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="normalFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="ConcourseT4-Regular.tff#Concourse T4-Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="ConcourseT4-Regular" />
        </OnPlatform>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="classicFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="OpenSans.tff#Open Sans" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

By using `x:Name` property, I'm setting `Text` for label and `Source` for image.

```
game1Date.Text = "asd";
team1.Text = "asd";
team2.Text = "asd";
flag1.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("flag1.png");
flag2.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("flag2.png");
```

The project builds without any problems, however, when I run the application in iOS Simulator or Android emulator, it crashes. The exception thrown is `System.InvalidCastException`. There's no inner exception as well. If I comment the Frame block from my xaml file, the application runs without any problems. I don't understand why this error is thrown and what is causing it.

Comment: If you put a Try/Catch around the `InitializeComponent()` call, you should be able to inspect the error at that point. That will help you determine if the error is occurring during the layout.

Comment: Also, can you post your `App.xaml` file or wherever you have your static resources defined? It could be one of your resources is the incorrect type.

Comment: @Andrew I had custom fonts and color elements defined in Resource Dictionary. When I removed the `{StaticResource font}` from `Font` properties and `{StaticResource color}` from `TextColor` properties, the error disappeared. One thing I don't understand is that I use these in other grids in the same file but for some reason, the app crashes if I use them in `Frame` block.

Comment: @Andrew upon further investigation, I found out the `Font` property is crashing the app. I'll investigate further and see why this is happening.

Comment: Interesting. If you post the Resource Dictionary and another one of the grids that is working correctly, that may help us find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Also, if you find the solution while you're troubleshooting, it's perfectly OK to answer your own question.

Comment: @Andrew ContentPage.Resource can be checked [here](https://pastebin.com/H1R3fnHV).

Comment: Please update your question to include the resource dictionary in case the link goes dead in the future. Also instead of setting `Font=`, try setting `FontFamily=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `Font="{StaticResource classicFont}"`. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.font?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Label_Font) that shouldn't be used.

To resolve the error, do `FontFamily={StaticResource classicFont}"`

Comment: deleting my answer as yours is the solution. Thanks for providing a link as well. Such a stupid mistake.